# MySQL database encoding with php

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have all tables and database encoded with utf8_general_ci and all data in database are ok.
When I select data with PHP (PDO) and print in CLI (and when I save these data into db) texts contains question marks:

```
Raw, zagra? te? rol? wiceprezydenta
```

Why ? What's wrong ?
I tried SET NAMES solution but don't work.
Part of my code:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL');
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
putenv('LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8');
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nameofdb;charset=utf-8','root','******', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
// body...
```

Comment: Does your *CLI* interpret UTF-8 correctly...?

Comment: Yes. The problem is even when I run script from browser (and of course set header charset to utf8)

Comment: Have you considred *everything* in [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)?

Answer (score 0):

The **charset** in your `$db` connection string should be `utf8` not `utf-8` like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nameofdb;charset=utf8','root','****', 
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work, nothing changed.